# Laptop USB ports no power, no data transfer

Tags: laptop, usb, port

my Dell laptops all USB ports stop working after use a charging cable to charge phone. now no power on USB ports and no data transferring. how to fix this problem?

I have tried most of the solution from web, including

*Driver Update

*USB root hub advance option.

*Open Battery and press power button,

all most everything but still not working.

if it is a motherboard issue, then how to fix it or what I can use to cover my USB Problem?
please help me.

Comment: If the ports are not working at all then it is very likely a hardware issue. The one thing you could do to further isolate hardware vs software would be to use a live Linux disk to boot temporarily into a different OS and see if USB works in there. If it does not, you have a serious hardware issue. If the laptop is under warranty you will need to contact Dell support. If it is not, replacement mainboards will usually cost a few hundred dollars minimum depending on the model.

Comment: @music2myear if I use a self powered usb hub, will it work?

Comment: Why do you think that would work? The self-powered hub still needs to connect to a USB port on your computer and needs power from there. Power isn't your problem: USB is. Power is a necessary part of the USB connection. Your USB connection isn't one part USB and one part Power. USB is not USB without power and will not work without power.

Comment: it's working with printer, scanner. and today I put a cable with battery then the others port started working and when I plugged out the battery cable then again stopped working

Comment: What is "it"? Are you talking about a power USB hub, or the laptop? Are you saying that when the laptop is plugged in to power the USB ports work, but when the power cord is disconnected the USB ports do not work?

Comment: Also, what is "cable with battery"? Is this an external battery pack you're using to power a USB hub or the laptop? Do you know that the battery pack provides the right amount of power for the device you're powering? Please be more clear in your descriptions. I'm finding I'm less and less certain what devices and systems you're using and where the problems are. Edit your question to clarify the EXACT device(s) you're using, HOW they are connected, and WHEN WHAT device(s) do and do not work.

Comment: It's a DELL Vostro laptop, The USB port working with any self powered device like printer, scanner.

Answer (score 0):

There is one final ultimate software test: Using a Live Linux disk (Ubuntu is probably easiest and most common) boot your laptop using Linux. This will entirely remove software from the diagnosis.

If the USB ports work in Linux, the problem is with Windows, and considering the steps you've already taken you'll probably need to reinstall Windows to resolve this.

If the USB ports do not work in Linux, the problem is with your computer hardware, primarily the mainboard, and it will need to be replaced either under warranty service, or manually by you.

Note, replacement laptop mainboards are expensive. It is not uncommon for them to be several hundred dollars depending on the laptop model, and it can also be difficult to find the specific model for your system.